# Teradata SQLSTR size

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I'm creating a SQLSTR variable as part of a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how large I need to make the SQLSTR. Is it based on the string length or the results?

Example:

```
DECLARE SQLSTR VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR S1;
SET SQLSTR='SELECT * FROM TABLE'; 
PREPARE S1 FROM SQLSTR;
OPEN C1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: A string is a string. Like this sentence. Make the variable large enough to hold your sql statement, which is a string. The resultset size will be handled by Teradata, so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Declare it as large as you want, there's no real reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata has a fixed limit of 1MB for a request length that includes the USING data and parcel overhead.